# c++ iterator and pointer usage in breadth first search

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, breadth-first-search

When using larger array dimensions, I have isolated my program's termination to always be during the breadth first search of the 2D array of vertices:

My Vertex class is declared

```
    class Vertex{                                                   
public:
    int i, j; 
    std::set<Vertex*> adj; //references to adjacent vertices (max of 4)

    //used in solving maze
    bool visited; 
    std::list<Vertex> path; //stores path from start vertex to this vertex

    Vertex();
    ~Vertex();
    //end constructors

    void setPos(int row, int col);

    /** for iterators */
    typedef std::set<Vertex*>::iterator iterator;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

};//END class Vertex
```

And in this function I have this subsection to perform BFS:

```
void solveMaze(string folder, Vertex arr[][MAZE_WIDTH]){
    //<randomly generate begin and end positions in maze>
    //<ensure all vertices are marked unvisited>

/* BFS */
list< Vertex > shortestPath; //shortest path from start to end
queue<Vertex*> q; //store visited vertices with one or more unvisited adjacent vertices while searching graph

arr[ begini ][ beginj ].visited = true; //mark start vertex as visited, as the search will begin here
arr[ begini ][ beginj ].path.push_back( arr[ begini ][ beginj ] ); //all paths begin at start vertex
q.push( &arr[begini][beginj] );

//explore all vertices in maze
while( !q.empty() ){ 
    Vertex* cur = q.front(); //next vertex to backtrack
    q.pop();

    //for all vertices adjacent of cur
    Vertex::iterator it; //thanks to typedef
    for(it = (cur->begin()); it != (cur->end()); it++){
        //if adjacent vertex has not been visited
        if( !(*it)->visited ){ 
             (*it)->visited = true; //mark vertex visited
             (*it)->path = cur->path; //save directory from start vertex..
             cout << "1\n";
             ((*it)->path).push_back( **it ); //..to this vertex     i think this line is main problem
             cout << "2\n";
             q.push( &arr[ ((*it)->i) ][ ((*it)->j) ]); //current path continues, so store vertex to backtrack later
        }
    }

    //path to end found, so store it if it's shortest found
    if( (cur->i) == endi && (cur->j) == endj ){
        if( shortestPath.empty() )
            shortestPath = ( cur->path );
        else if( (cur->path).size() < shortestPath.size() )
            shortestPath = cur->path;
    }

}//end while( !q.empty() )

cout << "    -finished breadth first searching\n";
...
```

So during BFS, 1 2 1 2 ... print repeatedly, but slower and slower until a last 1 prints and then it terminates with the error such as below:

```
...
1
2
1
2
1

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
make: *** [makeExec] Error 3
```

So I suspect it's something I'm doing wrong with pointer/iterator usage etc., like in my line in the while loop above "((*it)->path).push_back( **it );" since a 1 lastly prints then it terminates, but it only happens when using larger array dimensions.

Can someone help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: At what array size do you run into problems? Have you checked if you are running out of memory? Since `path` is storing the `Vertex` by value I would expect memory usage to explode pretty fast as you increase the number of vertexes and connections between them.

Comment: Vectors are usually faster than lists.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
std::list<Vertex> path; //stores path from start vertex to this vertex
```

to

```
std::list<Vertex*> path; //stores path from start vertex to this vertex
```

Worked beautifully.  Should've known the resources I was wasting, thanks @uesp!